# mean of non zero elements - why are these two attempt returning different results?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am attempting to return the mean of non zero elements in each column in my matrix;

my first attempt was:

```
i = 1:peopleCount;
nonZero1(i,:) = mean(nonzeros(Y(:,i)));
```

that returns the same result for all columns, while my second attempt:

```
for i = 1:peopleCount;
    nonZero2(i) = mean(nonzeros(Y(:,i)));
end
```

returns the correct answer.

They look identical to me, but obviously, they are not.

1. what went wrong in my first attempt?
2. how can i make the first version work?

Comment: Why not just do `nonZero = mean(nonzeros(Y))`? [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) automatically calculates the means of each column if the argument is a matrix.

Comment: `nonzeros(Y)` will return all non zero elements in the matrix, but will lose the information as to which column each element came from (a long vector will all on zeros)

Comment: Do you have `for` in first attempt? You can't expect `nonzeros(Y(:,i))` to return a matrix with variable size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out the `nonzeros` gives back a column vector, so you cannot expect multiple means, the same value is assigned to every element of `nonZero1(:,i)`.

A possible solution without loop:

```
A        = Y(:,i);
A(A==0)  = NaN;
nonZero3 = nanmean(A,1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-destructive (without changing the input matrix)  and a one-liner method -

```
mean_col_vals = sum(Y,1)./sum(Y~=0,1)
```

The trick is very simple - We get the sum along each column and divide it by the number of non-zero elements which are the elements that actually contributed to the summation values. Also, since `mean` internally calls `sum`, so we are avoiding one function call overhead with this technique!